# Where should I send an Ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, web

When using jQuery, when sending an Ajax request you specify the URL to send to. For example:

```
$.get("someurl", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

My question is: should the URL reference a page on the server, as if the client-page is located on the server? E.g. something like `mypage/something`? Or should the URL reference the page as if it's on another computer, using a hardcoded host-address, such as `http://192.168.1.1/mypage/something`?

It seems both approaches work. If so, than how does the client-browser know where to send the request if I only specify a file name, and not a full IP address?

Comment: by default and for security reasons, cross-domain requests aren't allowed. If it is not a cross-domain request, both will work,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be either.  If the page is in the same application you can reference it by name.  If it is in a different application or different website, you would reference it with the full path.

Comment: Thing is, the page is located on the server while the ajax-sending page is on the client machine. How can the client-browser know where to send the request, if I don't specify an IP address?

Comment: Is the page hosted on the client machine or is the client machine just accessing a page on your sever?  There is a difference.  If the client is hosting the page and the URL you want to access is on the server, you would have to specify IP or domain.  If you are hosting both the source page and the ajax page, then what I said before applies.

Comment: @Aviv: domain name or ips are set in the headers. It simply prepends your domain, (localhost, some ip or fully qualified domain name) whatever it is to all your requests. You don't have to worry about them. Browser will handle those things for you. It is the job of the server to resolve these paths. Don't worry that is automatically done.

Comment: @elf I see. So I can specify a path that is relative to where the 'client-page' is located on the server?

Comment: @Tim: I think you are talking about a cross-domain request which is prevented by default for security reasons. even if you enable those on the browser side, it is not a good practice and certainly the users are not going to enable them.

Comment: @elf I agree with you on the cross-domain point.  My answer was just stating when to use full path versus relative path that's all.

Comment: Okay. I was just clarifying things.